# Is it possible to prioritize non-JavaFX threads over the JavaFX thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, thread-priority

I have a JavaFX application that I'm receiving information from hardware with, using:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

the problem being, sometimes, if not always, I want to prioritize the data collection for accuracy. Is there an alternative to runLater that perhaps halts the JavaFX thread temporarily? Or is it possible to have an application where the JavaFX thread is a sub-thread?

Comment: How often do you call `runLater`?

Comment: I have two listeners, one for data received, one for changes in a TextArea (as a result of data received). Both call runLater.

Comment: TextArea listener is irrelevant as a user couldn't type fast enough to generate lots of runLater calls. How often do you receive data?  What I am trying to work out is why you believe [setting thread priority](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/09/why-thread-priority-rarely-matters.html) would make any desirable difference at all in your case?

Comment: Serial data at a baud rate of 115200.

Comment: Do you mean that you are calling `runLater` up to 115 thousand times a second?

Comment: Double that actually.

Comment: That's insane ;-) JavaFX pulses are by default limited to 60 per second, so there is no need to call runLater more often than 60 times a second, otherwise you will needlessly flood the JavaFX event dispatcher resulting in horrible performance.  Anyway, looks like you got your solution which is to batch up your input data then periodically shunt data in batches off to the JavaFX thread for processing via runLater().

Comment: I just upvoted this... not because I approve of what the OP wants to do but because I think to downvote a question like this is mean-spirited and contrary to the constructive spirit of SO: yes, the question springs from a perhaps naive understanding of organising Threads and tasks.  But posing a naive question is not the same as posing a useless or irrelevant or otherwise annoying question. And also because concurrency is simply a huge, complex topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Halting a JavaFX thread, will result in freezing the UI !**

I hope you are not looking for it !

If you want to prioritize the data collection part, just run it on a different Worker thread([Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)), *which will run parallel to the JavaFX thread*, and once the data collection is completed, use the `runLater` to update it back to the UI !

Comment: When you say "freezing the UI" does that mean permanently or temporarily? Because the application being temporarily non-responsive is also an option for my solution.

Comment: As long as the JavaFX thread will be on Halt, the UI will remain unresponsive. Since, you cannot be absolutely sure, how long it will take to collect data, this would result in a poor user experience. You must really look into [Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm), as I would not recommend your approach.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into it.

Comment: I ended up using `runLater` in a timer to periodically append the data, reducing the number of calls. I must have forgotten what my own code was doing, because it seems the data gathering was on a separate thread from the JavaFX Application thread (I don't think it would have worked otherwise), it was just appending for every data input event, calling runLater way more often than optimal. So +1 for "**once the data collection is completed**".